# Unable to run on non-Dell system (Alienware)

Tags: boot

Newly installed Ubuntu version 20 on my pc and after restart I'm stucked at the message unable to run in non-Dell system...how do I fix it ?

---

Yes I installed from the Ubuntu iso file and the reason for installing an older version is because what I intend using it for supports only this older version...

Answer (score -1):

Did you install Ubuntu from the Ubuntu 20.04 iso file that you downloaded from the official Ubuntu website? Dell doesn't recommend using its OEM installation media to install Ubuntu on any computers except for reinstalling Ubuntu on the original OEM computer. Dell also generally recommends that you install packages from the default Ubuntu repositories whenever possible.

In case it's relevant the latest LTS version of Ubuntu is currently Ubuntu 22.04.